# zsh, modifying an old command in history

Tags: command-line, ssh, zsh

Sometimes I have to repeat a command I typed **ages** ago, so I do something like:

```
$ history | grep ssh

195  ssh josetocino@eq1
209  cd .ssh
211  cat id_rsa.pub | ssh josetocino@eq1 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
212  ssh josetocino@eq1
```

And I see that I want to repeat command number 211 **but** changing the remote host. How can I do that?

Is there a command/shortcut to just paste that command in the shell so I can edit it manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Use `ssh-copy-id` to automate this specific command.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> and type part of the command to quickly retrieve it from history.
- Run `fc 211` to edit the command in $EDITOR.
- Use `!211:s/eq1/eq2/` to replace a word and then run the command.

Comment: Wow, that's an impressive and useful answer. Thanks.